# MProgressWindow does not refresh in Autodesk Maya API

Tags: c++, api, progress-bar, maya

I have an `MProgressWindow` class reference in Maya/C++. However the window stays at 0% (or even stays blank sometimes) and does not go up. What am I doing wrong?

```
MProgressWindow P ;
P.reserve() ;
P.setProgressMin( 0 ) ;
P.setProgressMax( 1000 ) ;
P.startProgress() ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {

        // do some work
        if ( i % 100 == 0) {

            P.setProgressStatus( "Progress "+ MString() + i + "/" + MString() + P.progressMax() ) ;
            P.advanceProgress( 100 ) ;
        }
    }
    P.endProgress() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one progress window in Maya, so you do not instantiate it yourself, it is already there vs one you will put in a dialog. That's why you do not see anything happening, you instantiate a memory object. Try this instead.

Side note - all methods are static so you call them by the base class name and ::

```
if ( !MProgressWindow::.reserve () )
    return ;
MProgressWindow::setInterruptable (true) ;
MProgressWindow::setProgressRange (0, 1000) ;
P.setProgress (0) ;
P.startProgress () ;
for ( int i =0 ; i<1000 ; i++ ) {
    if ( i != 0 && MProgressWindow::isCancelled () )
        break ;

    <do some work>

    if ( i % 100 == 0 ) {
        MProgressWindow::setProgressStatus ("Progress " + MString () + i + "/" + MString () + P.progressMax ()) ;
        MProgressWindow::advanceProgress (100) ;
    }
}
MProgressWindow::endProgress () ;
```

Comment: @LaurentCrivello, did it help?